# should pointers be signed or unsigned in c

Tags: c, int, microcontroller

I have a function `get_picture()` that takes a picture. It returns a pointer of type uint8_t (where the pciture is stored) and takes a pointer to a variable
that stores the length of the picture.

Here is the declaration:

```
uint8_t * get_picture(int *piclength)
```

Here I call it in `main()`:

```
unsigned int address, value;
address = (unsigned int)get_picture((int*)& value);
```

My question is - becuase `address` is storing an address (which is positive) should I actually define it as an `int`.

Comment: Why are you storing the pointer value in an `int`?

Comment: pointers should point to their types. `int*` should point to `int`, `unsigned int*` should point to `unsigned int`, `uint8_t*` should point to `uint8_t`, `struct myCoolStruct*` should point to `struct myCoolStruct`, etc. The exception being `void*` and `char*`, these can alias other types.

Comment: _It returns a pointer of type uint8_t_ : no it doesn't,  it returns a pointer __to__ uint8_t.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure you understand pointers.

If your function returns a `uint8_t *` then you should be storing it in `uint8_t *` not an int.

As an example:

```
uint8_t* get_picture(int* piclength);

int piclength;
uint8_t* address;
address = get_picture(&piclength);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add the `int *piclength` parameter and a matching variable in case OP is confused by your example.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to convert a data-pointer to an integer, use the dedicated typedef instead of some random (and possibly too small) type:
`uintptr_t` / `intptr_t` (Optional typedefs in `<stdint.h>`)

Still, the need is rare, and I don't see it here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are really after.  Your code is fine as is if you want address to contain the address of where that picture lives.  Likewise you could use an int, since bits is bits, int is the same number of bits as unsigned int and whatever consumes address can be fed those bits.  It makes more sense as a human to think of addresses as unsigned, but the compiler and hardware don't care, bits is bits.

But depending on what you are doing you may want to as mentioned already, preserve this address using a pointer of the same type.  See Dragan's answer.

If you want to "see" the address then it depends on how you want to see it, converting it to an unsigned int is one easy and generic way to do it.

Yes, this is very system dependent and the size of int varies by toolchain and target and may or may not completely hold an address for that system, so some masking may be required by the consumer of that variable.

So your code is fine, I think I understand the question.  Signed or unsigned is in the eye of the beholder, it is only unsigned or signed for particular specific operations.  Addresses are not themselves signed nor unsigned, they are just bits on an address bus.  For a sane compiler unsigned int and int are the same size, store the same number of bits so long as this compiler defines them as at least the size of the address that this compiler uses for a pointer, then this will work just fine with int or unsigned int.  Int feels a little wrong, unsigned int feels right, but those are human emotions.  The hardware doesn't care, so long as the bits dont change on their way to the address bus.  Now if for some reason the code we don't see prints this variable as a decimal for example `printf("%d\n",address);`  (why would you `printf` on a microcontroller?) then it may look strange to humans but will still be the right decimal interpretation of the bit pattern than is the address.  `printf("0x%X\n",address);` would make more sense and be more generic.  if your `printf` supports it you could just `printf("%p",address);` using Dragan's `uint8_t *` address declaration, which is what many folks here are probably thinking based on classical C training.  vs bits are bits and have no meaning whatsoever to the hardware until used, and only for that use case, an address is only an address on the address bus, when doing math on it to compute another address it is not an address it is a bit pattern being fed into the alu, signed or unsigned might depend on the operation (add and subtract dont know signed from unsigned, multiply and divide do).

If you choose to not to use `uint8_t *` address as a declaration, then unsigned int "feels" better, less likely to mess you up (if you have enough bits in an (unsigned) int for that compiler to store an address in the first place). A signed int feels a little wrong, but technically should work.  My rule is only use signed when you specifically need signed, otherwise use unsigned everywhere else, saves on a lot of bugs.  Unfortunately traditionally C libraries do it the other way around, making a big mess before the stdint.h stuff came about.